# elastic search edge_ngram issue?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

i have edge_ngram configured for a filed.

suppose the word is indexed in edge_ngram is : **quick**

and its analyzing as : **q,qu,qui,quic,quick**

when i am tring to search **quickfull** the words contaning **quick** is also coming in results.

i want words only containing **quickfull** comes else it gives no results.

### this is my mapping :

```
{
  "john_search": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "drugs": {
        "properties": {
          "chemical": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "cutting_allowed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "is_banned": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "is_discontinued": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "manufacturer": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 2,
            "fields": {
              "exact": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 4,
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "phenotic": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
              }
            },
            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "refrigerated": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "sell_freq": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "xtra_name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1475061490060",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "my_metaphone": {
              "replace": "false",
              "type": "phonetic",
              "encoder": "metaphone"
            },
            "autocomplete_filter": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "3",
              "max_gram": "100"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "autocomplete_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "dbl_metaphone": {
              "filter": "my_metaphone",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "qoRll9uATpegMtrnFTsqIw",
        "version": {
          "created": "2040099"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your name field has `"analyzer": "autocomplete"`, which means that the  `autocomplete` analyzer will also be applied at search time, hence the search term `quickfull` will be tokenized to `q`, `qu`, `qui`, `quic`, `quick`, `quickf`, `quickfu`, `quickful` and `quickfull` and that matches `quick` as well.

In order to prevent this, you need to set `"search_analyzer": "standard"` on the `name` field to override the index-time analyzer.

```
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "boost": 2,
        "fields": {
          "exact": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 4,
            "analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "phenotic": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"           <--- add this 
      },
```

Comment: thnx for the answer